# Limit the amount of categories to display:

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I need some assistance, I have put together this PHP code, which is displayed below. However for some reason I seem to be struggling to display only 6 child categories for a specific parent category.

```
<?php

$args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0' );
$categories = get_categories( $args = '' );
if ( $categories ) {
    echo '<ul class="categories">';
    foreach ( get_categories() as $category ) {
        $link = get_term_link( $category );
        echo '<li>';
        $size = "thumbnail";
        $image = get_field( 'featured_image', 'category_' . $category->term_id );
        echo '<a href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
        echo '<span class="cat-title"><a href="' . $link . '">' . $category->name . '</a></span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use something like this,

```
<?php

$args = array( 'hide_empty' => '0' );
$categories = get_categories( $args = '' );
if ( $categories ) {
    echo '<ul class="categories">';
    foreach ( array_slice(get_categories(), 0, 6) as $category ) {
        //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^
        $link = get_term_link( $category );
        echo '<li>';
        $size = "thumbnail";
        $image = get_field( 'featured_image', 'category_' . $category->term_id );
        echo '<a href="' . $link . '"><img src="' . $image . '" /></a>';
        echo '<span class="cat-title"><a href="' . $link . '">' . $category->name . '</a></span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

as of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate the help. Works like a charm!

Comment: I wont, I just wanted to test. The amount limited is good. However how do I specify a certain parent category in the PHP?

Comment: sorry, i didn't catch your last question, about specifying certain category, bit more detailes please, i will help...

Comment: I have multiple categories. Top 1 is Continent, second would be the countries and then there cities. I only need to display the category cities. Currently it displays all categories that have posts. Which is not ideal.